# Using a variable in a JavaScript function for Discord RPC

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, discord

I have been trying for a short while to try and get Discord RPC working so it updates the song title when fetching. I am aware that the sleep function probably won't work at the moment, but the main problem is being able to use the variable of "text" as an output to Discord RPC. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can use the "text" variable in rich presence?

````
const clientId = 'REDACTED';
const scopes = ['rpc', 'rpc.api', 'messages.read'];

const client = require('discord-rich-presence')(clientId);

const website = 'https://jetstreamradio.com/scSongData'

//var text = '';

function updateRichPres() {
    fetch(website)
        .then(res => res.text())
        //.then(text => console.log(text))
        .then(text => res.text())
        .then(function (text) { return text })
        .then(client.updatePresence({
            state: text,
            details: 'Now listening to...',
            startTimestamp: Date.now(),

            largeImageKey: 'jetstream_logo_tunein',
            //smallImageKey: 'jetstream_logo_tunein',
            instance: true,
        }));
    while (true) {
        //await sleep(60000);
        console.log('x');
    }   
};
client.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('connected!');
    updateRichPres()

});```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a function to .then(). What happens here is that the client.updatePresence call is made before the fetch is even completed, since you are calling it directly, not providing it as a callback.

It should instead be:

```
fetch(website).then(res =>
    client.updatePresence({ 
        state: res.text(),
        details: 'Now listening to...',
        startTimestamp: Date.now(),
        largeImageKey: 'jetstream_logo_tunein',
        instance: true 
    })
);
```

The arrow (=>) is JavaScript syntax for creating a function.

I would suggest learning more about base JavaScript syntax before using it in this quite complex use case.